# How to pass a nested PHP-Array via AJAX-Post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, post

I have a PHP-Script that expects:

```
$_REQUEST['asdf']['bsdf']['csdf']
```

to be set when it is called, and I cannot change this.
I want to call this PHP-Script via ajax:

```
myurl = 'example-url.com';
myid = $(this.$element).attr('id'); //gets the id of a textfield: csdf
value = 'somevalue';

$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: myurl,
        data: {'asdf[bsdf][myid]': value},
        success: function (data) {
          /* blabla */
       }
});
```

It does not work though, because the var "myid" is not filled with the supposed value "csdf".
Can someone help me how to do this?

PS: I cannot access the PHP-File, so no changes in structure possible...

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` say?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var myurl = 'example-url.com';
var myid = $(this.$element).attr('id'); //gets the id of a textfield: csdf
var value = 'somevalue';

var param = {};
param[myid] = value;

$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: myurl,
        data: {'asdf[bsdf]' : param},
        success: function (data) {

                 }
});
```

You can build the param object outside the data you pass via the ajax call to keep the correct key in place.

Comment: thank you so much, that did the trick! took me hours yesterday trying around :-)

Answer (score 0):

in JS

```
... {
     ...
     data: {[['first', 'array', 'nested'], 'other', 'in', 'parent', 'array']},
     ...
}
```

In PHP getting the POST vars is with other sentence

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php